# Swift Parser document with child element

Tags: ios, parsing, swift

I am realizing swift in a parser that is able to read this document (example):

```
    <Category id="0">
     <Name>Name</Name>
      <Category id="0.1">
       <Name>Name</Name>
        <Category id="0.1.1"> 
         <Name>Name</Name>
          <Category id="0.1.1.1"> 
           <Name>Name</Name>
           </Category>
          </Category
        </Category>
       </Category>
     </Category>

 <Category id="1">
     <Name>Name</Name>
    </Category>
```

as you can see, I have a document that has elements that in turn have children. So it is a recursive class.

How can I handle this? even if you do not know swift is not interested, even some advice on how to implement accepted.

I was thinking about this: When I find "Category Father" create new item in the list and save the object "Category" in a variable "CurrentItem" and every time I do I find the child: 
currentItem.children.append (new ..) 
and save again ogetto.

Finally when I close "Category father" I reset the object

What do you think? Any advice on how to save the object? Other tips?

NB: I avoided paste the code because it is quite long. If you need to put it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "So it is a recursive class. How can I handle this?" - using recursion, in first place. Parsers are often recursive, anyway.

Comment: how to use recursion? as I said in the example? saving the current object?